# Parsing multiple variable types from a line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got an input file with years and ratings that looks like this:

```
1997    4.2
2004    1.2
1908    3.6
...
```

The years need to be processed as integers and the ratings need to be processed like floats.

I'm wondering if there is a single-line / more pythonic way of reading in the lines than what I'm currently doing:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    year, rating = line.strip().split('\t')
    year, rating = [int(year), float(rating)]
```

Comment: is this file stored in dataframe ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal nope, just .txt files on disk. Context is map-reduce data processing in hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in one single line by using a lambda:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    year, rating = (lambda x: (int(x[0]), float(x[1])))(line.split())
```

but IMHO it is harder to read than your 2 lines solution, so unsure whether it is more *pythonic*...

Maybe the csv module could be used if the data are tab or space delimited...

Answer (score 0):

Try `map()` function:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()    
l = list(map(lambda x: (int(x[0]),float(x[1])),[i.split('\t') for i in s.split('\n')]))
```

example input:

```
1997    4.2
2004    1.2
1908    3.6
```

example output:

```
[(1997, 4.2), (2004, 1.2), (1908, 3.6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that you can do it and other answers seem correct, But I think there is a more simple way.

Until you are sure that each line has following pattern: `int\tfloat`, you can use `literal_eval` to convert your embedded types to string to native python types.
Here is your simple code:

```
from ast import literal_eval

for line in sys.stdin:
    year, rating = [literal_eval(x) for x in line.strip().split("\t")]
```

This code works very simple. As you used if, so you know what `line.strip().split("\t")` doing.

We assigned `year` and `rating` variables to elements of the `[literal_eval(x) for ...]`. So first and second element of this list will assign to them. In the list literal, we split the original line, and convert each element of generated list to native python types using `literal_eval`. So after that, there is an `int` in the `year` and a `float` in the `rating`.